# SQL Select all values from column with minimum characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables inside a database, Barcodes and Products.

I have extracted this table using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Barcode INNER JOIN Product on Barcode.ID = Product.ID
```

[image]

Now I'm trying to select all values from COLUMN barcodes that have minimum characters of 8. I have tried adding this code end of the one above:

```
SELECT join barcode.barcode from barcode where len(barcode.barcode) > 8
```

Should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: What about negative values, like `-1234567890`?

Answer (score 5):

If it is an integer datatype (the data looks right aligned) then just:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE number >= 10000000
--AND number <= 99999999 to match exactly 8 digits
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM barcode inner JOIN product ON barcode.id = product.id

select join barcode.barcode from barcode where len(barcode.barcode) > 8` this is the code i have used. Its not executing it

Comment: how would I select all characters that are NOT 6 and 7 characters? but select all that below 5 and above 7?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `LEN` function, after casting the second numeric column to text:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE LEN(CAST(col2 AS varchar(10)) >= 8;
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE LEN(CAST(col2 AS varchar(10)) >= 8; what does the 10 represent?

Comment: @Eduards 10 here - is the size of varchar data type.